# ¿Cómo mostrar la barra de desplazamiento vertical en SharePoint 2013?

Tags: lista, scroll, sharepoint

Estoy trabajando con una lista la cual tengo un grupo de usuario que solo pueden leer y añadir. Por este nivel de acceso no presenta la barra de desplazamiento, ni siquiera puede desplazar atravez del ‘mouse’.

Buscando información encontré que por el SharePoint Designer, modificando en el Master Pages el Seattle.master presenta la barra de desplazamiento incluyendo lo siguiente:

```css
<style type="text/css">
 #s4-workspace 
 {
  overflow-y: scroll !Important;
 }
</style>
```

Magnifico presenta la barra de desplazamiento pero es del tamaño del espacio presentado y prácticamente no se mueve.

Barra Incorrecta:

[image: Barra Incorrecta]

Necesito saber ¿cómo podría presentar la barra de desplazamiento? y que solo ocupe el espacio justo y que pueda desplazar la información presente.

Barra Correcta:
     [image: Barra Correcta]

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te puedo dejar un ejemplo de lo que necesitas, lo mas conveniente es que la informacion la metas en un div y el scroll solo se maneja dentro de ese div, el espacio que tu necesites lo modificas con el width y height; espero que te sirva de ayuda. Saludos!

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width: 200px; height: 500px; background-color: grey; overflow: scroll;">
       <p > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga voluptatum nemo quam sit in architecto minus, natus accusantium voluptas laudantium obcaecati amet voluptates nostrum, maiores soluta rem dicta. Maxime, obcaecati.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, laudantium asperiores nulla quibusdam neque nihil iste iusto. Consequatur consequuntur non quis laboriosam sequi, culpa earum fuga! Fugiat alias voluptates tempore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim nemo, consectetur consequuntur minus dolorum asperiores quam dolore obcaecati, illo explicabo perferendis nisi voluptatibus quo officiis temporibus alias ab necessitatibus unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde reprehenderit laborum voluptates possimus hic perspiciatis dolores repellendus molestias aperiam consectetur quos voluptatum placeat eaque provident fugit adipisci, eos amet atque?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores molestias nam, delectus, sapiente quas expedita odio at, fugit eum suscipit placeat. Natus quae eveniet amet ab porro, in similique quaerat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt quaerat cumque, voluptatem repellendus nesciunt vero corporis repudiandae laborum et sequi nemo facilis, quos architecto porro excepturi beatae illo, ducimus sunt!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quisquam eum accusamus asperiores ab adipisci architecto, facere doloremque nihil error. Suscipit nobis eaque omnis saepe, sequi earum, porro illo quidem. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos debitis sequi mollitia ex nemo fugit neque repellendus tempora doloremque veritatis qui, possimus, iure, corporis ullam ratione praesentium vero quaerat. Ut!</p>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no me resuelve ya que es de una página de SharePoint y no es un HTML normal, es mucho mas complicado que eso.